# MIDI notes getting stuck

Tags: midi

I have a MIDI keyboard (Axiom 61) connected to the USB port of my PC. The keyboard has never functioned properly with this PC. MIDI signals seem to come thru very randomly causing notes either not to play at all or getting stuck.

I started to think the problem is on the keyboard itself until I tested using it with my laptop. And everything works just like expected there! So, it must be a problem with my PC. I did a fresh install of the operating system (Manjaro, had Ubuntu before). No luck, the problem persists.

Can you help me narrow down the problem and ultimately find the solution?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

PC specs:

```
Motherboard
Manufacturer:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name:    H97M-D3H

CPU
Architecture:    x86_64
Model name:      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1231 v3 @ 3.40GHz
Virtualization:  VT-x

➜  ~ lspci | grep USB
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
```

Things I have suspected to be the cause:

- Kernel (Tried multiple kernels and but couldn't find the solution from there. The laptop is running generic kernel, with the PC I have tried generic as well low-latency.)
- Messed up configurations (Fresh install should have helped but the problem still persists.)
- BIOS/UEFI (The laptop is in UEFI while the PC is in the Legacy Boot.)
- Hardware problem (I have suspected the keyboard but it's working fine with the laptop.)
- App/Software (I have tried various different software as well as reading the raw MIDI input. The problem exists no matter the software.)
- Cable (Could the USB cable cause problems? Although, the same cable works fine with the laptop.)

Also, weirdly, I have tried using a phone as a MIDI device and the problem didn't occur then.

---

Here's a (dmesg) log of what happens when I connect the MIDI keyboard. Something funny happening there as well.

```
[ 2800.432734] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2800.556039] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2816.259674] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 2816.489639] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 2816.630469] usb 2-1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[ 2816.630471] usb 2-1: can't read configurations, error -71
[ 2816.630497] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 2817.276371] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 2817.294740] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0763, idProduct=019a, bcdDevice= 1.05
[ 2817.294741] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2817.294742] usb 2-1: Product: USB Axiom 61
[ 2817.294743] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: M-Audio
```

Comment: Perhaps the USB power output of the PC is a little low, and the keyboard needs every bit of power a standard USB port can supply? You might try adding a powered USB hub in between the PC and the keyboard, and see if it has any effect. You might also add the make and model of your computer (or its motherboard) to the question; that way we might be able to tell if that particular model has any known quirks in its USB ports.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Updated the question with more information.
The MIDI keyboard seems to have enough power at least to light up the little LCD screen on it.